# The Triple Pendulum

Tags: matrices, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

> **Triple Pendulum**
>
> Consider the triple pendulum made out of three masses $m_1 = 2m$ and $m_2 = m_3 = m$ and attached on rods of negligible mass and the same length $\ell$ as depicted in the figure below and parameterized with the angles $\theta$, $\phi$ and $\chi$.
> [image: Triple pendulum]
>
> For small angles $\mid \theta \mid, \mid \phi \mid, \mid \chi \mid\ll 1$ the Lagrangian is given (up to an irrelevant constant) by,
> $$L=\frac12 m \ell^2\left(2{\dot{\theta}}^2+\left({\dot{\theta}}+{\dot{\phi}}\right)^2+\left({\dot{\theta}}+{\dot{\chi}}\right)^2\right)-\frac12gm\ell\left(4\theta^2+\phi^2+\chi^2\right)\tag{1}$$
> Show that we can perform a change of coordinates $(\theta, \phi, \chi)\to(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ so that the kinetic term is diagonalized and normalized, $T=({\dot q_1}^2+{\dot q_2}^2+{\dot q_3}^2)$.
> In terms of the vector ${\bf {q}}=(q_1, q_2, q_3)$, show that the Lagrangian can be expressed as follows,
> $$L=\frac12{\bf{\dot q}\cdot\bf{\dot q}}-\frac12{\bf qkq}\tag{2}$$
> and find an expression for the matrix $\bf k$.

---

So in $(1)$, I will let ${\dot{q_1}}^2=2m{\ell}^2{\dot{\theta}}^2$, ${\dot{q_2}}^2=m{\ell}^2(\dot{\theta}+{\dot{\phi}})^2$ & $\,{\dot{q_3}}^2=m{\ell}^2(\dot{\theta}+{\dot{\chi}})^2$.

Inverting these in favour of the angles gives
$$\dot \theta=\frac{\dot{q_1}}{\sqrt{2m}{\ell}}\tag{a}$$
$$\dot \theta +\dot \phi=\frac{\dot{q_2}}{\sqrt m\ell}\tag{b}$$
$$\dot \theta +\dot \chi=\frac{\dot{q_3}}{\sqrt m\ell}\tag{c}$$

Insertion of $(\mathrm{a})$, $(\mathrm{b})$ & $(\mathrm{c})$ into the first (kinetic) term of eqn $(1)$ gives
$$T=\frac12m\ell^2\left[2\frac{{\dot{q_1}}^2}{2m\ell^2}+\frac{{\dot{q_2}}^2}{m\ell^2}+\frac{{\dot{q_3}}^2}{m\ell^2}\right]=\frac12\left[{\dot{q_1}}^2+{\dot{q_2}}^2+{\dot{q_3}}^2\right]=\frac12{\bf{\dot q}\cdot\bf{\dot q}}\tag{3}$$

So I can correctly get the kinetic, ($T$) part of eqn $(2)$, now using the same method to get the potential part ($V$), from $(\mathrm{a})$, $(\mathrm{b})$ & $(\mathrm{c})$ it follows that
$$\theta=\frac{{q_1}}{\sqrt{2m}{\ell}}\tag{d}$$
$$\phi=\frac{{q_2}}{\sqrt{m}{\ell}}-\frac{{q_1}}{\sqrt{2m}{\ell}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}\ell}\left(q_2-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt2}\right)\tag{e}$$
$$\chi=\frac{{q_3}}{\sqrt{m}{\ell}}-\frac{{q_1}}{\sqrt{2m}{\ell}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}\ell}\left(q_3-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt2}\right)\tag{f}$$
From $(\mathrm{d})$, $(\mathrm{e})$ & $(\mathrm{f})$ it follows that
$$\theta^2=\frac{{{q_1}^2}}{2m{\ell^2}}\tag{g}$$
$$\phi^2=\frac{1}{m{\ell^2}}\left(q_2-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(q_2-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt2}\right)=\frac{1}{m\ell^2}\left({q_2}^2-\sqrt 2q_1q_2+\frac12{q_1}^2\right)\tag{h}$$
$$\chi^2=\frac{1}{m{\ell^2}}\left(q_3-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(q_3-\frac{q_1}{\sqrt2}\right)=\frac{1}{m\ell^2}\left({q_3}^2-\sqrt 2q_1q_3+\frac12{q_1}^2\right)\tag{i}$$
Now, insertion of $(\mathrm{g})$, $(\mathrm{h})$ & $(\mathrm{i})$ into the second term of $(1)$, $V=\frac12gm\ell\left(4\theta^2+\phi^2+\chi^2\right)$, transforms to
$$\begin{align}V&=\frac{gm\ell}{2m{\ell}^2}\left(4\frac{{q_1}^2}{2}+{q_2}^2-\sqrt 2q_1q_2+\frac12{q_1}^2+{q_3}^2-\sqrt 2q_1q_3+\frac12{q_1}^2\right)\\&=\frac12\frac{g}{\ell}\left(2{q_1}^2+{q_1}^2+{q_2}^2+{q_3}^2-\sqrt 2q_1q_2-\sqrt 2q_1q_3\right)\\&=\frac{g}{2\ell}\left(3{q_1}^2+{q_2}^2+{q_3}^2-\sqrt 2q_1\left(q_2+q_3\right)\right)\tag{4}\end{align}$$

I have really laboured the point with the algebra here, but I did so on purpose so it would be easy to identify errors.
This is as far as I can get, and it doesn't look anything like the second term of eqn $(2)$ - $\frac12{\bf qkq}$ . But I can tell you that the last expression (for $V$) is correct as I have the author's solution below:

> [image: Triple pendulum solution]

---

I have some questions regarding this solution.

1. Why is the authors eqn $(29)$ different from my eqn $(3)$ and what is meant by "the kinetic term is diagonal"?
2. My equation $(4)$ matches with the author's equation $(33)$ which is good. But how on earth do you deduce the kinetic matrix (sometimes known as 'mass matrix'), $\bf k$ from this?
3. Taking the matrix $\bf k$ as given for a moment, if ${\bf {q}}=(q_1, q_2, q_3)$ is a row vector, then the only way to compute $\bf qkq$ as matrix multiplication is to write it as ${\bf q}{\bf k}{\bf q}^T$ because $${\bf q}{\bf k}{\bf q}^T=\frac{g}{\ell}\begin{pmatrix}q_1 & q_2 &  q_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
   3 & -1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
   -1/\sqrt2 & 1 & 0 \\
   -1/\sqrt2 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}q_1 \\ q_2 \\  q_3\end{pmatrix}
   $$Which is in the format required for matrix multiplication (row times column) as from left to right we have matrices with (1x3) times (3x3) times (3x1) with the result being a (1x1) matrix (scalar) as required by equation $(33)$ or my $(4)$. So why is $(2)$ not being written as ${\bf q}{\bf k}{\bf q}^T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Equation (29) is an intermediate form for the variables $\bf \tilde q$, in the next step they get transformed so that your and the reference expression in $\bf q$ are the same.

2.) This is called "polarization", this can be done for any quadratic form. $\sum_{i\le j} a_{ij}x_ix_j$ can be written as ${\bf x}^TA{\bf x}$ with $A_{ii}=a_{ii}$ and $A_{ij}=A_{ji}=\frac12a_{ij}$ for $i<j$.

3.) This is indeed some sloppiness with the operations, one could write $\bf q·kq$ similar to the kinetic energy term, where $\bf q$ is a column vector and the dot signifies the scalar product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand $1.)$ completely now. But could you please expand on this 'polarization' procedure in $2.)$, as I still can't figure out how to get $\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
-1/\sqrt2 & 1 & 0 \\
-1/\sqrt2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ from $\frac{g}{2\ell}(3{q_1}^2+{q_2}^2+{q_3}^2-\sqrt 2q_1(q_2+q_3))$? Best regards.

Comment: @N.Ginlabs But the solution tells you, the $i,i$ entry of the matrix is the coefficient of $q_i^2$; the $i,j$ entry of the matrix is one half of the coefficient of $q_i q_j$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for the response, I don't see how the solution tells me this, since, as per my third question, I don't understand how to multiply these matrices. If someone could show me how to obtain $\frac{g}{2\ell}(3{q_1}^2+{q_2}^2+{q_3}^2-\sqrt 2q_1(q_2+q_3))$ from the ill-defined $\bf qkq$ I would probably understand what you are saying, but at present, this is not clear to me, sorry.

Comment: You understood that completely correctly in what you wrote in 3., the source is just somewhat short or incorrect in its notation of that vector-matrix-vector product. // In a physics text I would expect that all vectors that have no further qualification are column vectors.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for the reply, you write, "In a physics text I would expect that all vectors that have no further qualification are column vectors". So does it seem that  ${\bf q}{\bf k}{\bf q}=\frac{g}{\ell}\begin{pmatrix}q_1 \\ q_2 \\  q_3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
3 & -1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt2 \\
-1/\sqrt2 & 1 & 0 \\
-1/\sqrt2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}q_1 \\ q_2 \\  q_3\end{pmatrix}$ can be computed?

Comment: No, I already said that your formula in 3. is the correct one and that $qkq$ is incomplete, it should be $q·(kq)$ or $q^Tkq$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann What is meant by "the kinetic term is diagonal" (in my first question) please?

Comment: It means that the kinetic term is a sum of squares. The matrix associated to this quadratic functional is diagonal.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks very much for an excellent answer, could you please provide a link to this "polarization" procedure for finding the mass matrix $\bf k$?

Comment: This is seen so as so obvious that wikipedia just jumps over it. There are pieces of it in the "quadratic form" and "symmetric bilinear form " articles. You will probably find more discussion on this in sources on normed vector spaces on when the norm is generated by a scalar product. Strictly speaking, polarization is the construction of a bilinear form from a quadratic one, $b(v,w)=\frac12(a(v+w)-a(v)-a(w))$ or $b(v,w)=\frac14(a(v+w)-a(v-w))$. The bilinear form then has an obvious matrix representation in any basis.